# How to trigger jQuery change event in code

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a change event that is working fine but I need to get it to recurse.

So I have a function that is triggered on change that will "change" other drop downs based on a class selector (notice "drop downS", there could be more than one). This proxy change does not trigger the function and so fails. How can I get it to work?

#### Code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var activeDropBox = null;

    $("select.drop-box").change(function () {
        var questionId = $(this).attr("questionId");
        var selectedAnswer = $(this).val();
        activeDropBox = this;

        alert(this.questionId);

        $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: answerChangedActionUrl,
            data: { questionId: questionId, selectedValue: selectedAnswer },
            success: function (data) {
                SetElementVisibility(data.ShowElement, questionId);
            }, error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('XMLHttpRequest:' + XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                alert('textStatus:' + textStatus);
                alert('errorThrown:' + errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });

    function SetElementVisibility(visible, questionId) {
        // I would like each child to then trigger the change event...
        $(".childOf" + questionId)[visible ? 'show' : 'hide']('slow');
        
        // Suggested code
        //$(".childOf" + questionId + " select").trigger("change");

        if (!visible) {
            $(".childOf" + questionId + " select").attr('selectedIndex', 0);
        }
    }
}
```

The suggestions so far seem to work, but as the change event triggers an ajax post it now seems to fail here. I'm going to play around with it but that is something for another question I feel.

Comment: Provide some code so we can have a look

Comment: How can we tell you how to get it to work, when you haven't shown us what *it* is?

Comment: I thought it was a simple concept and didn't feel code was required. The answers so far seem to have understood my explanation and so I am trying their solutions now. If I don't have any joy I'll post some code. My implementation is actually much more complex.

Comment: Sorted it, was a problem with me changing the value after the ajax post. Thanks all for the help. The suggestions posted worked like a charm.

Answer (score 506, accepted):

Use the [trigger() method](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

```
$(selector).trigger("change");
```

Comment: Is there any benefit to this over `change()`? Or is it just preference?

Comment: @JoshPinter  no real benefit, more a preference.  But definitely easier to abstract as a parameter than a method name.

Comment: Setting a value before actually triggering change event is the best way!!

Comment: Latest versions of jQuery (3 atm) will raise a warning when using the deprecated shorthand `.change()`. You should use `.trigger('change')` instead.

Comment: lets celebrate with 500 vote. dear john. its really help ful for me

Answer (score 54):

For me

```js
$('#element').val('...').change()
```

is the best way.

> Note: `.change()` is deprecated in newer versions use `.trigger('change')` instead.

Comment: Yeah!, I like this one

Comment: Yes! it allows to choose option on the same time. I think your answer deserves to be the best here.

Comment: This is the only way to trigger change event when programmatically altering the element's value.

Comment: this is now deprecated. all best function essentials for development are getting deprecated... is it to make the developer keep learning new things always?

Comment: @AmitShah Yeah I think `.change()` is deprecated in newer versions but `.trigger('change')` can be used just as well. I think the jQuery team is tired of making shortcuts for functions. It is also easier to find the right function to call when the documentation is a lot smaller.

Answer (score 21):

The parameterless form of the [change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) method triggers a `change` event. You can write something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#yourInitialElementID").change(function() {
        // Do something here...
        $(".yourDropDownClass").change();
    });
});
```

Comment: this method is not getting Deprecated.

Answer (score 15):

```
$(selector).change()
```

[.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

---

### .trigger("change")

*Longer [slower](https://jsperf.com/jquery-change-vs-trigger-change) alternative, better for abstraction.*

[.trigger("change")](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

```
$(selector).trigger("change")
```

Answer (score 13):

Use That :

```
$(selector).trigger("change");
```

OR

```
$('#id').trigger("click");
```

OR

```
$('.class').trigger(event);
```

Trigger can be any event that javascript support.. Hope it's easy to understandable to all of You.