# How to fire select value change even in a combo box programmatically?

Tags: jquery

I've a combo box and want to select an option value. I'm using something like:

```
$("#comState_city option:eq(0)").attr("value",chk[i]);
$("#comState_city option:eq(0)").attr("selected","selected");
```

But this isn't firing value change event. I want the onchange handler be called when I changed the value of a select element.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to trigger jQuery change event in code.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247264/how-to-trigger-jquery-change-event-in-code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#comState_city option:eq(0)').trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one:**

```
$("#comState_city").change(function(){
    alert($(this[this.selectedIndex]).val());
});
```

Comment: -, it's not about adapting the change-eventHandler, it's about firing the change-eventHandler