# Javascript or JQuery to Sort

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I have a select menu (well three) - and the 2nd two populate based on the choices of the first one, a 1,2,3 selector... - I really need to sort the 2nd and 3rd ones except for the first row... and I've seen some snippets on how to sort it... but I cannot figure out how to get it to work since the code is fired on page load, and the menu isn't populated until a choice is made from first.

any help is greatly appreciated.

I think what I need is this, but I cant figure out how to make it work

[How to trigger jQuery change event in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247264/how-to-trigger-jquery-change-event-in-code)

Comment: Some code in jsfiddle to illustrate the issue would help

Comment: relationship between `<select>` elements is not clear at all...please be far more specific

Answer (score 0):

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wrxsti85/yLnpc/)

If I understood correctly, this should point you in the right direction for dynamically changing select menu options based on the previous selection.

Markup:

```
<select id="select1">
    <option disabled selected>Please select an option.</option>
    <option>Option One</option>
    <option>Option Two</option>
</select>

<select id="select2">
    <option>g</option>
    <option>b</option>
    <option>j</option>
    <option>c</option>
    <option>d</option>
    <option>h</option>
    <option>e</option>
    <option>h</option>
    <option>a</option>
    <option>i</option>
    <option>f</option>
</select>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).on('change', '#select1', function(){
    var options = $('#select2 option');
    var arr = options.map(function(_, o) {
        return {
            t: $(o).text(),
            v: o.value
        };
    }).get();
    arr.sort(function(o1, o2) {
        return o1.t > o2.t ? 1 : o1.t < o2.t ? -1 : 0;
    });
    options.each(function(i, o) {
        console.log(i);
        o.value = arr[i].v;
        $(o).text(arr[i].t);
    });
});
```

Hope this helps!

EDIT: Changed so that the first menu triggers a sorting of the second menu. Updated the fiddle as well.

Comment: thanks, that sure looks like it'll work for the "Change" function, what I'm trying to do is to sort the results of the dropdown, but there's nothing in it, until something is chosen from first, so there's nothing to sort :/

Comment: Do you know what the secondary menus options will be?

Comment: they are driven from a text file, so they can and do change monthly, which is why I am trying to have it just sort whatever is populated in...

Comment: So the first menu is really just a sorting option for the secondary menu?

Comment: it's a brand selector, then the 2nd is a series selector, the third is a model.... (cause there's hundreds of models)

Comment: will try this in the morning you rock, it looks like it will be great! :)

Comment: Good deal. Hope it helps!