# trigger select id after the submit failed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this `<select>` that when a user selects an option in there, performs an AJAX to the backend then show/hide additional `<select>`:

```
$('#select1').on('change', function() {
    // Get fruit information
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/path/to/ajax',
      data: {id: $(this).val()},
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (data) {
        if (data.type == "apple") {
          $('#select2').addClass('hide');
          $('#select3').addClass('hide');
        }
        else if (data.type == "banana") {
          $('#select2').removeClass('hide');
          $('#select3').removeClass('hide');
        }
      }
    });
});
```

This works fine. When I submit the form the backend performs a validation then if it fails it loads the page again, however, the `#select1` has the value I chosen earlier but the other `<select>` that suppossed to show is hidden. Is it possible to trigger `$('#select1').on('change', function()` when the page loads?

Comment: You want to trigger with ajax or the whole page reload?

Comment: @Bilal - I guess that would be the whole page reload.

Comment: These links may help `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247264/how-to-trigger-jquery-change-event-in-code` and `http://api.jquery.com/trigger/` . `$('#select1').trigger("change");` on page load. Not tested

Comment: @zamil - That is what first came to my mind, and I already did that but nothing happens.

Comment: You can pass a php variable as a flag indicating this select should be hidden or not and apply class hide if the flag is true. `<select name="select2" class="<?php if($select2) echo 'hide';?>">`

Comment: `trigger()` should work fine here. Where did you place `$('#select1').trigger("change");`? Is it before or after the `$('#select1').on()` event handler? I suggest you place it after the `on()` event.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the `.trigger()` of jquery

here is a simple demo to do so

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mayekarsaurabh/7w8TC/48/)