# How to trigger JS native even addEventListener("change",function) by JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, addeventlistener

*This is not a duplicate of [How to trigger jQuery change event in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247264/how-to-trigger-jquery-change-event-in-code), since that deals with the interaction of jQuery with **jQuery** event listeners, while this question discusses the interaction of jQuery with **native** event listeners.*

I use  **addEventListener** to bind a change event for an input, but  **$('#input').val('bbbb').change();** can't  trigger the alert, **how to trigger addEventListener("change",function)  function  by JQuery**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>code</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="http://o6flfbzth.bkt.clouddn.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>

    <input id="input" type="text" value="input" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("change", function() {
        alert(this.value);
    });
    </script>

    <input type="button" value="change input" onclick="  $('#input').val('bbbb').change();" />
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is not a duplicate

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot trigger a native event with jQuery's `.trigger('change')`.

You will need to [ceate a native event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) and [dispatch it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent):

```
const evt = new Event("HTMLEvents");
```

And then to fire it:

```
const el = document.getElementById("input");
el.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

**Deprecated:**

You will need to [create a native event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createEvent) and [dispatch it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent):

```
var evt = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
evt.initEvent('change', true, true);
//            ^         ^     ^
//            |         |     cancelable
//            |         bubbles
//            type
```

And then to fire it:

```
var el = document.getElementById("input");
el.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

Comment: evt.initEvent is now deprecated on everything but IE. Use new Event('change') constructor for modern browsers (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)

Answer (score 0):

Bind the change event using jquery.

```
$("#input").change(function() {
  alert(this.value);
});
```

Working snippet :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>code</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="http://o6flfbzth.bkt.clouddn.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>

    <input id="input" type="text" value="input" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $( "#input" ).change(function() {
        alert(this.value);
      });
    </script>

    <input type="button" value="change input" onclick="  $('#input').val('bbbb').change();" />
</body>

</html>
```